# I have two lwc components, each have recordId based on first component. how to pass the recordId to second component

Tags: lighting-web-component

I have two lwc components, each have recordId based on first component. how to pass the recordId to second component? I am able to pass recordId from Parent to first child but it is not passed to the second child.

```
<template>
    <c-hardware-order record-id={recordId}></c-zettle-hardware-order>
    <c-hardware-order-info record-id={recordID}></c-zettle-hardware-order-info>
</template>
```

in Parent Js :

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class Hardware extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}
```

in both child js :

```
@api recordId;
```

Still the record Id is not passed to the second child but it is passed to first child.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: show us the html code where you create the second component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with below line of code:-

```
<c-hardware-order-info record-id={recordID}></c-zettle-hardware-order-info>
```

You have passed **recordID**, instead you should pass **recordId**.

Correct syntax should be:-

```
<c-hardware-order-info record-id={recordId}></c-zettle-hardware-order-info>
```

> javascript is case sensitive.